# How to access to a parent node from a child node  using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div class"cA" >
   <div class="c..">
       <div class="cZ" >
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I from the div which has the class `cZ` get the div which has class `cA`, knowing that the number of divs between then is not specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) will walk the parent chain and accumulate the elements that match the specified selector. However, if more than one parent element matches the selector (in your case, if more than one parent `<div>` exposes the `cA` class), then the jQuery object that is returned will contain more than one element.

If that behavior isn't what you want, consider using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $parent = $('.cZ').parents('.cA');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .parents() method. It should return what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Look in to Jquery Tree Traversal API. The one that help you in this case is [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)